# Best way to indicate a TimeField with a lower hour comes 'after' TimeField with greater hour

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Daily Event model with a start_time and stop_time.

```
class DailyEvent(models.Model):
    start_time = models.TimeField()
    stop_time = models.TimeField()
```

If, for example, the `start_time` is 8pm and the `stop_time` is 3am, what's the best way to represent that the `stop_time` comes 'after' the `start_time`?

An idea I have is to add this field to represent that `stop_time` represents the next day:

```
stop_time_next_day = models.BooleanField()
```

I prefer not to use DateTimeField, because I don't want to use a fake placeholder date and prefer a cleaner solution than DateTimeField.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Why don't you use a DateTimeField?

Comment: As mentioned in the question I'd rather not use `DateTimeField`, mainly because I'm not representing a specific date but rather a daily event.

Comment: You can get the Time from a DateTime.

Comment: I'm looking for a better solution than adding a placeholder date.

Comment: If you have only a Time, you can't know if it's from the same day, the day before, or the next day, so I think you need the day.

Comment: @Gocht you can, using the first solution I proposed. I'm asking though if there's a better way than that.

Comment: How will you know if it is the next day? or two days after?

Comment: I only care if it's the next day. Maybe I don't even need a stop_time_next_day and the model will just imply that stop_time is always after start_time.

Comment: Yes, I think that's you best choice.

Comment: @Gocht Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @mcastle: Check edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've concluded that it's best to just have the model imply that `stop_time` always comes after `start_time`.

Answer (score 0):

As **@Gocht** said, use [DateTimeField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield)

```
class DailyEvent(models.Model):
    start_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    stop_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
```

So for example,

```
start_datetime = 2015-12-04 20:00:00
stop_datetime = 2015-12-05 03:00:00
```

should work in your case. What's your approach i.e. field `stop_time_next_day` will work only if `stop_time` is of the next day and will **fail** if the `stop_time` is more than 1 day further.

---

**Update:**

**Datetime** should be the best way.
You can write methods in your models for quick operations you are looking for. Or you can overwrite the save method.

```
class DailyEvent(models.Model):
    start_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    stop_datetime = models.DateTimeField()

    # try this
    @property
    def day_difference(self):
        # can use as stop_time_next_day
        return (stop_datetime-start_datetime).days

     # or try this
     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.stop_datetime > self.start_datetime:
            # raise Exception
        super(DailyEvent, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: As mentioned in my question, I'd rather not use `DateTimeField` because I'm not representing a specific date but rather a daily event.

Comment: You can take out `time` from datetime and also know the difference of days (1 or more)

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that does not require setting a placeholder Date.